# No AppxManifest is specified, but WindowsPackageType is not set to MSIX

Tags: maui

I have a very simple `.NET MAUI` app in VS2022 and I am getting this compile error:

> Improper project configuration: no AppxManifest is specified, but
> WindowsPackageType is not set to MSIX.

Before trying to compile, I did the following:

1. Unload project. Remove all lines references Windows, Mac, Tizen. I want this project to only work with iOS and Android.
2. Deleted the project folders related to Windows, Mac, Tizen

How can I get this to compile for iOS/Android only?

Comment: Hi, I found an issue like yours. Here is the website: https://github.com/dotnet/maui/issues/1431

Answer (score 3):

add a xml file with name Package.appxmanifest in platforms/windows....and paste content into it from any demo project of maui, or download a sample.